# loading a web page for a fake query string

Tags: javascript, ajax, nginx, server-side-includes

I don't even know how to phrase the title of this question, but hopefully the following description will explain my issue.

I have a web application that is made up of a single, bare search page with a search field. The search is actually performed by the client browser and results are loaded via ajax. In other words, the server does nothing but serve up the bare search page at `http://server/index.html`

Once the query is performed, I use `history.pushState()` to change the URI in the browser address bar to something more sensible like `http://server/index.html?q=searchterm&page=1&size=10`. Pagination is performed by `prev` and `next` links that too are called via ajax along with the appropriately incremented or decremented `page` and `size` values. All is good.

But, I want my application to be a good web citizen, and be bookmark-able. In other words, if someone enters `http://server/index.html?q=searchterm&page=1&size=10` directly in the browser address bar, I want to load the results correctly. Except, if I send that URI to the server, the serve will croak unless I implement some server-side processing. And, that is something I don't want to do as that will change the complexity of my application completely. *Unless* I can do that with plain, vanilla `nginx` (my web server). In other words, I don't want to implement any server side scripting other than what can be done with the web server itself, such as SSI.

So, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

hi the exact term for what you are trying to do is "Client side routing". It involves a combination of manipulating the browsers history using history.pushState() [which you are already doing] and server side config setting

- .htaccess if you are using apache
- config file if you are using nginx.

The server side settings will make your web server your base index.html for whatever request the browser makes(http://server/index.html?q=searchterm&page=1&size=10) once loaded in the client you have to get the query string in the window address bar and handle accordingly(make an ajax request).

This implementation has implications when search engines crawl your site using the URL but that is not within the scope of this question.

this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812550/configuring-nginx-for-single-page-website-with-html5-push-state-urls) will give you a start

Answer (score 0):

actually, I think this is a lot easier than I thought. When I send the browser to `http://server/index.html?q=searchterm&page=1&size=10`, it doesn't complain. It simply sends back `http://server/index.html`. Then it is just a matter for me to use `js` to extract the query string and do my ajax bit. This should work.