# How to make a route navigable from a URL with VueJS

Tags: nginx, vue.js

My apologies as I don't know the correct terminology for this issue, which perhaps is half my problem...

I've created an SPA with VueJS – a small portfolio site – and am currently using VueRouter to create a `/information` route.

I want this route to be shareable by URL – so that if I link you to `www.example-url.com/information`, then this should load that route. However at the minute I get the error message: `404 Not Found nginx/1.8.1`

Is a pre-render plugin like https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin the appropriate solution to this problem? From my understanding this would solve the issue, but it's not explicitly advertised as a benefit of pre-rendering so I'm a little unsure.

Here is the site in question: http://isabellaburley.com/information

Many thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring nginx for single page website with HTML5 push state URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812550/configuring-nginx-for-single-page-website-with-html5-push-state-urls)

Comment: Have you build the files on your server already?

Comment: @Daniel A. White But I don't want to point the `/information` url to the index.html – I'd like it to load the `/information` route when visited – that's not the same issue, is it?

Comment: @SimonRogers thats what that page is for.

Comment: @RuChernChong As in SSR? No I haven't.

Comment: You can point `/information` to the `index.html`. If the route is configured, vue will know and work properly.]

Comment: You need to use the router in the hash mode: http://isabellaburley.com/#/information

Answer (score 0):

add this to your nginx vhost config:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

    ...
}
```